# How to make tick label with subscript bold?

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, label, subscript

I have the following dictionary with labels, where I'd like to plot K1/2 as K with subscript 1/2.

```
labels = {'label': 'Label1', 'Label2', '$K_{1/2}$'}
```

I then want to plot the xticks in bold and size 22, however, K1/2 is not plotted in bolt as only label. How can I fix this?

```
plt.xticks(fontweight = 'bold', fontsize = 22)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me!

```
 plt.xlabel(r'$\bf{K_{1/2}}$')
```